# Create one table/view with two different columns from the same source

Tags: sql

I have a table with a column which contains odd and even numbers (ex. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc).

I have to create an output table or view with two columns, odd_numbers and even_numbers, like this:

```
odd_numbers   even_numbers
1             2
3             4
5             6
```

How do I do that? The condition is easy (where mod (num,2) = 0 or <> 0) but how do I populate the view?
I can't figure it out.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: .  I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses conditional aggregation:

```
select min(num), max(num)
from t
group by floor( (num - 1) / 2)
```

Note that this doesn't use `mod()`.  It basically divides the number by 2 to identify the row (the `- 1` is just so the min is odd and the max even).

EDIT:

MS Access (and some other databases) does integer division, so you can just use `group by (num - 1) / 2`.

If some number can be missing, then:

```
select max(iif(mod(num, 2) = 1, num, null),
       max(iif(mod(num, 2) = 0, num, null)
from t
group by floor( (num - 1) / 2)
```

Comment: It doesn't work in Access (where I am testing it).
The name of my column is "page".
I don't get what "num" is in your example.
Is it a function?

Comment: @Stef . . . If you are using MS Access, then tag *only* with MS Access.  The original answer here is standard SQL.

Comment: I am trying in both. 
But as I told you I don't understand your query. What is "num", if floor is the name of the column? Thanks.

Comment: @Stef . . . `num` is the name of the column, as used in your question.  `floor()` is a function.

Comment: Thanks. "floor" doesn't exist in Access, that's why I was confused.
However, there is "int", in Access.
But the query result is
1, 2
3, 4
6, 6
instead of
1, 2
3, 4
null, 6
(when 5 is missing).

Comment: @Stef . . . Your sample data doesn't have such gaps, but conditional aggregation solves that problem.

Answer (score 0):

This runs in Access (and most other dbs):

```sql
SELECT 
    Value AS Odd, 
    Value + 1 AS Even
FROM 
    Table1
WHERE 
    Value Mod 2 <> 0
```

Comment: Thanks! And what about if the table were 
number, text
like: 
1, xxx
2, yyy
3, zzz
and I had to create a query which returns:
null, xxx
yyy, zzz
This is also a problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Then post a new question including representative sample data as well as the desired output.